# getEntityManager in PHPunit class test

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

I am in my phpunit test class  extending Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase

I would like to get the entityManager to get some data in the database.

How can I do that?

It looks like I have to initialize the parent::kernel, but I dont know what 4 arguments I should pass to the constructor.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code should work:

```
static::bootKernel();
$entityManager = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Comment: the method getDoctrine is a shortcut of the base controller class

Comment: Call to undefined method getDoctrine()

Comment: Extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    $em = self::getKernel()->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Comment: Call to undefined method getKernel()